# Copy cells based on row count macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros, rowcount

I have two workbooks. I need to take the row count from workbook 1 (call this "rowcount") then copy the first row in workbook 2 down the number of rows in "rowcount".

Workbook 2 is a template that has a series of equations in the cells and pulls in data from workbook 1.

This is wrong, but hopefully lays out the idea:

```
I=WORKBOOK1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1",Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    WORKBOOK2.Worksheets("Sheet1")Range("C1").Select
    Range(Selection, ("C1:CI")).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help you.

```
Sub Macro1()


    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("C3:L3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

1. select sheet2
2. select the required range
3. copy the selection
4. select sheet1
5. go to next available row (going from the bottom to the top) used from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239282/3664960)
6. paste what was copied

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Sub main()
    With Workbooks("Wb1Name").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Workbooks("Wb2Name").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

just change "Wb1Name" and "Wb2Name" to your actual "workbook 1" and "workbook 2" workbooks names