# Aggregate data from different Excel files into one main file

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Let's say I have 3 excel files and they have multiple sheets

ExcelFile1 (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)
ExcelFile2 (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)
ExcelFile3 (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)

Using a VBMacro how can I merge all the content of Sheet2 from each of those files into one file? Only the content of Sheet2 needs to be merged/appended such as it looks like this:

ExcelAggregateFile (Sheet1) - where Sheet1 has all aggregated content appended at the bottom from all the Sheet2 of other files.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Essentially, you just want to copy a range from `Sheet2`, paste to your main WB, Sheet1, starting at the [next empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238596/vba-go-to-last-empty-row).

Answer (score 0):

Load this AddIn.  It will do what you want.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yep76.png)