# Get td items in webpage

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on Excel macro and trying to get the items in a `td` elements to Excel. However, the HTML code has no `td` id which made me lost.

HTML code

```html
<Tbody>

<Tr class = rptodd><td>1.</td> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Apple</td><td>200</td></tr>


<Tr class = rpteven><td>2.</td> <td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Orange</td><td>500</td></tr>
```

VBA Code

```
Set doc = ie.document
Set colTR = doc.getelementsbytagname("table")

For each tr in in colTR 
    ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = tr.innertext
```

I know my codes are incorrect or somehow not relevant. 
Can someone guide me for doing the right way?

I want to get the apple value in A1 sheet1 which is 200
And orange value 500 in A2

Comment: Why not just `Set colTD = doc.getelementsbytagname("td")` and loop that to get the innertext? Unless of course you don't just want the TD but the row/column structure of the HTML table as well.

Comment: I already did that but it scrape all the td elements. I just want the value. Can you show me the complete codes how to loop in each td? Btw, thank you!

Comment: Is it that you only want the td's that have values and to ignore the ones that are empty? Given your example table with two rows, what would you want the output to look like?

Comment: Yes, i just want to get the td 200 and 500. May output is 200 in A1 in 500 in A2. Ignore the other td

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but can you give me an idea or the proper code for this problem?

Comment: Had to run out real quick. So... I believe in the HTML Document there is a `lastChild` or a `lastElementChild` (Can't remember which, if either, is in the VBA library). First set your `colTR` with `Set colTR = doc.getelementsbytagname("tr")` And then in your `For Each` try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = tr.lastChild` IF that works properly then `A1` should have the last-last child value of `500`. Then you just have to get one to go into A1 and the next into A2 and so on which can be done with a variable that increments in the loop.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this. So lastchil means getting the last value of each tr? Hows that work for the first?

Comment: There may be a `.FirstChild` as well. Alternatively you can iterate through each child inside your existing `for Each` loop like `For each child in tr.Children` and deal with them in that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JNevill stated, get all the `td` tags. Then you can loop them and if they have `innerText` you are looking for (`Apple` and `Orange`) then you can get the `innerText` of the `nextElementSibiling`.

I did this below using late binding using `Variant` but would suggest doing it early binding.

Also I used a `Case` statement, but you could also use a standard `If` statement.

```
' Get all the `td` tags
Dim tableDataNodes As Variant
Set tableDataNodes = Ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("td")

Dim dataNode As Variant
For Each dataNode In tableDataNodes

    ' See if innerText of `td` is a value you are looking for.
    Dim fruitValue As String
    Select Case dataNode.innerText
        Case "Apple"

            ' Get the text of the next sibiling
            fruitValue = dataNode.nextElementSibling.innerText

            ' Add value to range or whatever you want to do with it.
            ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = fruitValue

        Case "Orange"

            ' Get the text of the next sibiling
            fruitValue = dataNode.nextElementSibling.innerText

            ' Add value to range or whatever you want to do with it.
            ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2").value = fruitValue

    End Select

Next dataNode
```

Comment: Did you run the locals window and see if it was getting the correct elements? Hard to tell without having the url. I used the sample HTML you provided and it worked for me.

Comment: I managed to get it workin, now i my question is how to put the value 200 in A1 sheet and 500 in b1. Thanks btw for your time!

Comment: Well based on your question it is very specific cells `A1` and `A2`. I updated my example to show that specific question. In case you actually want to keep adding to the next available row then see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239282/8309643). That is a common question you can look up all the different ways to do it and get the pros and cons.